# matplotlib: get the value on the x-axis where a horizontal line from y-axis meets the curve

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to make a plot like the image below, and get the values on the x-axis where two horizontal lines from y = 60 and y = 10 respectively intercepts the curve.

[image]

Here is the code for the plot I already have.

```
y = [99.8900, 99.4400, 44.3200, 18.8600, 3.7800, 0.8900, 0.1800]
x = [2.8000, 1.8000, 0.6000, 0.4250, 0.250, 0.1250, 0.0053]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color="green", marker='o', markerfacecolor='red')
ax.set(xlabel='Particle Diameter (mm)', ylabel='Percentage Finer (%)',
       title='Grain Size Distribution curve')
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
ax.set_xlim(0.001, 100)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) can calculate the intermediate values. Some care has to be taken:

- `y` has to take the place of `x` in the documentation, as we are searching for the `x` value that corresponds to a given `y` value
- `x` and `y` need to be reversed, because `np.interp` needs the values in increasing order
- `np.log` needs to be taken of the `x` array, to take the log scale into account; `np.exp` will be needed on the resulting value.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = [99.8900, 99.4400, 44.3200, 18.8600, 3.7800, 0.8900, 0.1800]
x = [2.8000, 1.8000, 0.6000, 0.4250, 0.250, 0.1250, 0.0053]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, color="green", marker='o', markerfacecolor='red')
ax.set(xlabel='Particle Diameter (mm)', ylabel='Percentage Finer (%)',
       title='Grain Size Distribution curve')
ymin = 0
xmin = 0.001

y1, y2 = 10, 60
x1, x2 = np.exp(np.interp([y1, y2], y[::-1], np.log(x[::-1])))
for xi, yi in [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]:
    ax.hlines(yi, xmin, xi, color='r')
    ax.vlines(xi, ymin, yi, color='r')
    print(f'x-value corresponding to y={yi}: {xi:.3f}')
ax.set_ylim(ymin, 100)
ax.set_xlim(xmin, 100)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
x-value corresponding to y=10: 0.311
x-value corresponding to y=60: 0.820
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Oh nice. So what if I wanted to print out the values, maybe assign them to variables x1, x2 respectively, I need them for some other calculation.

Comment: You probably upvoted the answer. To accept it you should click on the tick mark on the left.